# Facebook: OAuthException: This authorization code has been used

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl, facebook-login

**Background:**

I know that this question has been asked before, I have gone through all answers I have found, but it seems that no one have given a satisfying answer to it yet. I have seen that Facebook had a bug open about this but closed it due to lack of info. Thats why I ask again to see if someone out there now have found any good solution.

I'm trying to get a short-lived access token to be able to get a users profile. This worked fine up until some time ago and now I only get "OAuthException: This authorization code has been used." back from the api call.

**Technologies used:**

- PHP (no third part libraries or Facebook SDKs for Facebook API interaction)
- cURL
- Graph API
- https

**Logical Flow**

1. Get the url for the login dialogue looking similar to this:

   https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=[APP_ID]&redirect_uri=[URLENCODED_REDIRECT_URI]&display=popup&scope=publish_stream
2. Login through the Facebook login dialogue. On success redirect
   the user to the specified callback URI and add the "code"
   quersy-string variable.
3. When the user is redirected to the specified callback URI it
   immediately try to get get a short-lived accesstoken with the "code"
   variable provided by the Facebook login dialogue. I do that by
   calling this url:

   https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=[APP_ID]&redirect_uri=[URLENCODED_REDIRECT_URI]&client_secret=[APP_SECRET]&code=[CODE_SENT_FROM_FACEBOOK]

I receive the following response EVERY TIME:
{"error":{"message":"This authorization code has expired.","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}

**I already know that:**

1. I shall get a short-lived access token
2. the code is only valid for 10 minutes
3. I can only use the code once (my logging confirm that I only call
   the access_token request just once)

What have I missed? Why has it suddenly stopped working? 
Any answer, tip or trick is very appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried exchanging the short-lived token for the long-lived token and use that instead? It should just be one extra step to insert into your code.

Comment: you're sure you don't have a redirect loop somewhere? That error comes when you've already used the code to get an access token or when the code has expired...Post some of your PHP maybe.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16054033/facebook-graphapi-oauth-how-to-get-access-token

Comment: I am having this issue too, but am calling $session = $helper->getSession(); everytime the user refreshes the page or visits a new page.  Have not found out how to fix it yet either :(

Answer (score -1):

If I understood.

this token change everytime when you log in on facebook.

You need to get a new token always you make a new login.

Comment: This is technically correct, but does not help or aid the OP.